# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' when trying to 'print'

Tags: python

```
def findLongRepeats(strToSearch):
"""Search strTosearch to find the first location of longest repeated string 
of a single digit e.g '1111'. Do this for each digit from 0 to 9"""
numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
for number in numbers: #reads a number line one at time
    number_count = 0 #sets the count to 0
    number = int(number)
    longrepeats = []  #creates a new list
    for x in strToSearch: #reads each digit one by one
        if x == number: #if x is true it will add 1 to the number count
            number_count += 1
        if x != number: # if x is not flase it will add number count into the long repeat list
            longrepeats.append(number_count)
            number_count = 0
    print "Found", max(longrepeats), number+'\'s in a row at character position', strToSearch.index(number*max(longrepeats))

def main():
    """DocT"""
    File = open("pidigits.txt","rU") #opens file for reading
    Thousand_String = 0
    strLine =''
    for line in File: #reads each line
        line = line.strip()
        if '3.' in line:
            line = line.replace('3.','')
        Thousand_String += len(line)
        strLine += str(line)
        #print line
    #File.close()



    print
    print "Number of pi digits to process:",Thousand_String
    print
    findLongRepeats(strLine)
    print line
main()
```

"When i run the function findLong Repeats -- get a this error :

```
File "PA5_.py", line 53, in main
    findLongRepeats(strLine)
  **File "PA5_.py", line 18, in findLongRepeats
    print "Found", max(longrepeats), number+'\'s in a row at character position', strToSearch.index(number*max(longrepeats))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

I can't figure out how to fix the error please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a string (`'\'s in a row at character position'`) to a number `number`. The proper way to interpolate numbers into strings is to use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings) not addition:

```
print "Found {0} {1}'s in a row at character position {3}".format(max(longrepeats), number, strToSearch.index(number * max(longrepeats)))
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine if OP actually wants number to be an int, but I'm pretty sure that the cast to int is unnecessary in the first place.  That being said, even without casting to int some nice formatting would still be better.

Comment: @NolenRoyalty Right, even if he wants to interpolate strings into strings he should still use string formatting.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply I'll try that out.  I just posted the output, so you can get a better idea what this code is suppose to produce.

Comment: @PHZEOXIDE You seem to have added an unrelated question in your edit. If you have another problem with the code, not related to the `TypeError`, you need to ask it in a new question.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to use String formatting as noted above, here is the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings

Another simple way to solve this issue is not to add using "+", but independently print the int and string variables separated by a comma:

```
print "Found", max(longrepeats), number,'\'s in a row at character position', strToSearch.index(number*max(longrepeats))
```